# How to correctly implement view content behind statusbar when using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-statusbar

I'm trying put my ImageBackdrop from the collapsing toolbar behind the statusBar, I've done it right with the Drawer and the navigationView but I can't do it with my fragments, In the cheesequare demo, Chris did it, and I can do it that way, but it's not using a single activity app and fragment transitions, so that's not quite what I'm looking for.

**My style:**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
```

**My v21 Style:**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

**My Main Activity:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_main"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/window_background_white"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/title_text_color"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**My content_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

**My fragment:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    style="@style/AppTheme.CoordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.CollapsingToolbar.Text.Transparent"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.CollapsingToolbar.Text.Transparent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlwaysCollapsed|enterAlways"
            app:title="">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView_backdrop"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/detail_backdrop_height"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView_expanded_title"
                    style="@style/AppTheme.CollapsingToolbar.TextView.Multiline"

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"/>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        style="@style/AppTheme.RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Another Fragment where I don't need the content behind**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    style="@style/AppTheme.CoordinatorLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/about_tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <ViewSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/viewSwitcher"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/progress_bar_color_primary"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/about_viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </ViewSwitcher>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

***What I've accomplished:***

If I put `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` in the DrawerLayout I can accomplish the desired effect in the fragment where I have the CollapsingToolbar but in the ViewPager I've a strange grey statusBar.

**Desired effect accomplished badly with `android:fitsSystemWindows="false"` in the drawerLayout:**

[image: Desired effect]

**But in the second fragment the content it's behind the statusBar, where I don't want it.**

[image: One of the issues]

**What I've read:**

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31190612/fitssystemwindows-effect-gone-for-fragments-added-via-fragmenttransaction),

[Medium](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: Sorry for the delay answer. Yes i find out the solution. Take a look my answer and see if it's the same problem ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was the content_main.xml it's always replaced so I thought it wasn't necessary to have the android:fitsSystemWindows attribute but i was wrong, adding android:fitsSystemWindows="true" solved the problem.

**snippet content_main:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"/>
```

**Important:** if like me after that you find a bug in viewPager when coordinatorLayout has android:fitsSystemWindows="true" take a look here: [CoordinatorLayout status bar padding disappears from ViewPager 2nd page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368781/coordinatorlayout-status-bar-padding-disappears-from-viewpager-2nd-page)

Answer (score -2):

NavigationView extends ScrimInsetsFrameLayout which does the magic. Copy paste has got you covered.

Comment: What do you mean? Yes, there is this layout, but changing FrameLayout to ScrimInsetsFrameLayout hasn't helped.

Comment: @CoolMind using ScrimInsetsFrameLayout with windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds set to true in the theme and fitSystemWindows="true" should normally move its content behind the statusbar