# DrawerLayout - Opaque Status Bar Over Drawer and Translucent Status Bar Over Container

Tags: android, android-layout

I've tried searching SO a few hours and couldn't find anything relating to what I want. Most questions are in relations to making the Navigation Drawer appear behind the status bar.

However, this isn't the behavior that I want.

I want the status bar to remain opaque over the Drawer, but is transparent over the DrawerLayout container (the fragment).

Here's what I have:

[image]

And here's what I want:

[image]

I can get the status bar to be translucent over other activities, except for the main activity which has the DrawerLayout. Because everytime I try to make the status bar translucent only the Drawer can become translucent, which is exactly the opposite of what I want for the Drawer. The status bar should only be translucent over the fragment.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <!-- This FrameLayout is the container for all other fragments
    so I want this to have a transparent status bar because some fragments
    may have "cover photos" that needs to take up the status bar. It looks
    nicer that way. I tried playing around with the fragment layouts    
    themselves. Bit nothing seems to budge, so I give up on that part. -->
    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_main_nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_profile.xml** (one of the fragment to be placed inside the container)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_cover"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    app:cardElevation="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#11b4ff"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"/>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_profile"
                    android:layout_below="@id/card_cover"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    app:cardElevation="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-60dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#1119ff"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
                        />
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/card_cover"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/card_profile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Profile Name"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/fragment_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**v21\styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more searching on SO I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35467576/how-to-correctly-implement-view-content-behind-statusbar-when-using-fragments) answer that although didn't directly solve my problem, it gave me clues as to what was going on. In order to enable the translucent status bar in the fragment I needed to change the container layout to a CoordinatorLayout.

Furthermore, I needed to add "fitsSystemWindows=true" to all child views in order for the inset to be placed correctly in my desired fragment.

Here's the updated code that gave me the desired result:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/activity_main_nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**fragment_profile.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#fff"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_cover"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dp"
                    app:cardElevation="10dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#11b4ff"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"/>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/card_profile"
                    android:layout_below="@id/card_cover"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dp"
                    app:cardElevation="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-60dp">
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="#1119ff"
                        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon"
                        />
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_margin="15dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/card_cover"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/card_profile"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Profile Name"
                    android:textSize="30sp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/fragment_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="6dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```